# Get Internet Access on a Android device from a smartphone without hotspot

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-wifi, wifi-direct, tethering

I have an Android device that has wifi and Bluetooth modules. I want to build applications to connect the device to the internet using a smartphone's data connection. Is this possible?

The smartphone will have wifi as well as data connection. Can the smartphone's data connection be shared through [Bluetooth](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/transfer-data)? Or is there better alternatives like [wifi-direct](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct) or [NFC](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc)? I am aware that enabling Hotspot on the smartphone is an option. But with hotspot, the issue of wifi being turned off makes it not usable for my use case. Is there any alternative to wifi-hotspot?

What will be the best option for this and what things should I consider when building my applications and services?

Answer (score 0):

NFC is definitely not the answer, the data rate is far too slow and the connection unreliable and the OS does not allow it.

You might be better with a USB ethernet adapter if your phone support USB On The Go (OTG)

Comment: Sorry, I missed adding that I want to do this programmatically. And I want this to be done wirelessly.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone should already support sharing a data connection using Bluetooth. This is called [Bluetooth tethering](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9059108?hl=en#zippy=%2Ctether-by-bluetooth). But you also have wifi, so wifi tethering is also an option to share your data connection. No additional app is required.